# Importing massive dataset to Neo4j is extremely slow

Tags: java, mongodb, neo4j, database

I have a rather large dataset, ~68 million data points. The data is currently stored in MongoDB and I have written a Java program that goes through the data to link data points together and place them in the Neo4j database using Cypher commands. I ran this program with a test set of data (~1.5 million) and it worked, ran it overnight. Now when I try to import the whole dataset, the program is extremely slow. Ran the whole weekend and only ~350,000 data points have made it. Through some short testing, it seems like Neo4j is the bottleneck. It's been half an hour since I stopped the Java program but Neo4j's CPU usage is at 100% and new nodes are still being added (from the Java program). Is there anyway to overcome this bottleneck? I've thought about multithreading, but since I'm trying to create a network, there are lots of dependencies and non-thread-safe operations being performed. Thanks for your help!

EDIT: The data I have is a list of users. The data that is contained is the user id, and an array of the user's friends' ids. My Cypher queries look a little like this:
`"u:USER {id:" + currentID + "}) CREATE (u)-[:FRIENDS {ts:" + timeStamp}]->(u" + connectionID + ":USER {id:" + connectionID + "})"` 
Sorry if this is really terrible, pretty new to this

Comment: can you share some of the example queries. if you use MERGE or MATCH make sure to have indexes or better constraints on those Label + property combinations.

Comment: i think if you are using java you should use java neo4j api this is much faster. The cypher query have to be translated.

Answer (score 1):

You should first look at this:

[neo4j import slowing down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386260/neo4j-import-slowing-down?rq=1)

If you still decide to DIY, there's a few things you should look out for: First, make sure you don't try to import all your data in one transaction, otherwise your code will spend most of the time suspended by the Garbage Collector. Second, ensure you have given plenty of memory to the Neo4j process (or your application if you're using an embedded instance of Neo4j). 68 million nodes is trivial for Neo4j, but if the Cypher you're generating is constantly looking things up to e.g. create new relationships, then you'll run into severe paging issues if you don't allocate enough memory. Finally, if you are looking up nodes by properties (rather than by id) then you should be using labels and schema indexes:

http://neo4j.com/news/labels-and-schema-indexes-in-neo4j/

Answer (score 1):

Did you configure neo4j.properties and neo4j-wrapper.conf files?
It is highly recommended to adjust the values according to the amount of RAM available on your machine.

in conf/neo4j-wrapper.conf I usually use for a 12GB RAM server

```
wrapper.java.initmemory=8000
wrapper.java.maxmemory=8000
```

in conf/neo4j.properties I set

```
dbms.pagecache.memory=8000
```

See http://neo4j.com/blog/import-10m-stack-overflow-questions/ for a complete example to import 10M nodes in a few minutes, it's a good starting point

SSD are also recommended to speed up import.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I learned when loading bulk data into a database was to switch off indexing temporarily on the destination table(s).  Otherwise every new record added caused a separate update to the indexes, resulting in a **lot** of work on the disk.  It was much quicker to re-index the whole table in a separate operation after the data load was complete. YMMV.